# Liferay creating community using API

Tags: jakarta-ee, liferay

Here is the code:

```
ServiceContext serviceContext = new ServiceContext();
serviceContext.setAddCommunityPermissions(true);
serviceContext.setAddGuestPermissions(false);
logger.info("setAddGuestPermissions");
try {
    GroupLocalServiceUtil.addGroup(        
                100L,
                "testing",
                CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment(),
                "abc",
                "the abc",
                3,
                null,
                true,
                false,
                "abc-abc",
                0L,
                serviceContext,
                ture);
    } catch (PortalException ex) {
        //--
    } catch (SystemException ex) {
        //--
    }
```

Getting the following error from weblogic:

```
ERROR [GroupLocalServiceImpl] Error adding default application layouts
```

Any thoughts what I'm doing wrong? How to solve this?

Comment: Could you refactor your code? `ture` after `serviceContext` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @rp. removed it and got same error, flipped it to false and not getting the error anymore but not getting application created either. Is there a lead for a clear documentation on how to do create application using APIs? I'm using Liferay 5.2